# How to SELECT rows that has same values in column 1 but different values in column 2?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this query below:
[image]

I've managed to filter out the names with the SAME YEAR but DIFFERENT TID, then how to I pick these names out without duplication?

OUTPUT:
OK the desire output should be like this per request.

```
firstname | lastname | year | tid
Alex        Hannum     1956   MI1
Alex        Hannum     1956   ROC
Alex        Hannum     1956   STL
Alex        Hannum     1956   SYR
Alvin       Attles     1969   PH1
Alvin       Attles     1969   SFW
Alvin       Attles     1970   PH1
Alvin       Attles     1970   SFW
Andrew      Levane     1952   MI1
Andrew      Levane     1952   ROC
Andrew      Levane     1952   SYR
```

.... and so on.

Comment: if you want to avoid duplicate names then  you  can't see TID

Comment: Not entirely clear to me.  Can you at least show us the expect output from the above screen capture?

Comment: from the question its not clear what output you are expecting. share the table data and exact output you are expecting, then we call can guide you to accomplish your task..

Comment: I've edited the desired output

Comment: Don't post images for sample data / query or expected o/p. Only post text data.

Comment: @KaushikNayak What do you mean text data

Comment: The way you have pasted the desired o/p, the same way you should post the query and your sample data from the table. It is important becoz I (infact many others here) cannot open the images in workstation m/c due to restrictions. Moreover, it is hard to replicate the scenario using images.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the players who opt-out two or more tid in a year,

If so you can use the below query on the data you displayed in screen-shot assuming it also has one more column which identify players uniquely.

SELECT `firstname`,`lastname`,`year`,`tid` FROM `player` where `player_id` in (select distinct `player_id` from `player` group by `firstname`,`lastname`,`year` having count(*) >1)